# how to create an aligned array of integers in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

My current code is:

```
a = new int[10];
```

and the address of `a` is `0x...040` I want it to be `4096` byte aligned so I tried to change it to:

```
a = new __declspec(align(4096)) int[10];
```

but still this doesn't work (the address is still ends with `040` instead of with `000`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__declspec(align(...))` can be used for static arrays, like:

```
__declspec(align(4096)) int a[10];
```

For dynamic allocation use `_aligned_malloc` function, use `_aligned_free` to release array allocated by `_aligned_malloc`:

```
int* a = (int*) _aligned_malloc(10 * sizeof(int), 4096);
...
_aligned_free(a);
```

Required include is malloc.h

Comment: error "_aligned_malloc" id undefined ? yes I have included the header